# Haunts 'weakness: slow': manifests at initiative rank 0?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm a novice DM who's somewhat new to Pathfinder, so this could be a basic question.

[An example Haunt weakness](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mastery/haunts.html#elements-of-a-haunt) is 'weakness: slow (manifests at Initiative rank 0)'.

[Slow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mythicAdventures/mythicSpells/slow.html#slow-mythic) I think I understand, and I can see how this affects the Haunt [adds a -2 penalty to the Haunts AC against positive energy].

What does "manifests at initiative rank 0" mean, and how does it impact me (both as a player and as a DM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the haunt is *Slow*, it doesn't suffer the effects of the spell *slow* but instead manifests at initiative rank 0 in the surprise round. That's because usually...

> **When a haunt is triggered, its effects manifest at initiative rank 10 in a surprise round.** All characters in the haunt's proximity can attempt to notice the haunt at the start of this surprise round by making a notice check). All haunts detect life sources and trigger as a result of the approach of or contact with living creatures, but some haunts can be tricked by effects like hide from undead or invisibility.

As a DM it means the haunt will likely be detected before it gets to act. As a PC, it means--unless your initiative modifier is *horrible*--reacting to the haunt before it fully manifests if it's noticed.

Comment: Oh. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks very much! :)